# How to split the dictionary with in list

Tags: python

Dictionary is below

```
{ "id": "234", "name": "Manger", "policies": [ { "id": "13", "name": "P"}, { "id": "14", "name": "PMO" } ]}
```

I need to split into two whilie printing

```
{ "id": "234", "name": "Manger", "policies":  { "id": "13", "name": "P"}
{ "id": "234", "name": "Manger", "policies":  { "id": "14", "name": "PMO" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your policies prepreti in your initial dictionary.

```py
old_dict={ "id": "234", "name": "Manger", "policies": [ { "id": "13", "name": "P"}, { "id": "14", "name": "PMO" } ]}
new_dict = []
for policy in old_dict["policies"]:
  tobe_add = old_dict.copy()
  tobe_add["policies"] = policy
  new_dict.append(tobe_add)

print(new_dict)
```